# Force corrplot color label to display integers only

Tags: r, integer, label, r-corrplot

I'm using corrplot and trying to get only integers in the color label.
I'm plotting a non-correlation matrix, and I want my color label to contain a range greater than the max() in the matrix (which is 85).

I can use `cl.lim` to display the range that I want (from 1 to 107), and I can set the number of labels I want to get displayed with `cl.length` , but I get floats. Floats are meaningless in my dataset, therefore, I want to force the labels to be integers, even if not equally spaced, or even if the first or last numbers are not displayed.

Is there a way to do that?
I've seen there is the `colorlegend()` function, but I have not found a way to integrate it into the `corrplot()` call. Is the only solution to do a corrplot with no legend and make the legend independently?

My code:

`corrplot(mymatrix, is.corr= FALSE, method = "color", tl.col = "black", order = "hclust", cl.lim= c(1,107), cl.length= 10)`

My matrix:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F G  H  I
A 83 51 38 40 15 40 2 39 67
B 51 60 22 27 10 40 1 27 48
C 38 22 44 26 10 17 2 27 37
D 40 27 26 47  8 24 1 29 37
E 15 10 10  8 18  7 1  7 15
F 40 40 17 24  7 48 1 20 38
G  2  1  2  1  1  1 3  3  3
H 39 27 27 29  7 20 3 44 35
I 67 48 37 37 15 38 3 35 85
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi @XiBon, could you solve your problem yet? I know its been a long time already, Im facing something similar..

Comment: hi @MJimitater,
Unfortunately not. I made a plot with no legend and made the legend independently.
Another subpar solution I used was to change my `cl.lim` at different combinations until I got no floats. In my case, adjusting one number up was enough (so `cl.lim = c(1,108)` instead of c(1,107) ). This is of course not ideal, but for me it was not a problem.
Sorry I cannot help.